# Dyld fatal in Xcode 7.0 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dyld

please help me. I using Xcode 7.0 and my app working in iOS Simulator, but when I compile and run in device (iPhone 5s) the following message:

```
dyld`dyld fatal error :   0x120039088 <+0>: brk    #0x3
```

You can download my project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9kcpme97trs9y27/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I tried running on my device (iPhone 6), Cleaning the project then trying again did it for me.

You can also try the solutions suggested [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18181) if this did not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Dyld is is the dynamic linker that is the part of an operating system (iOS) that loads and links the shared libraries for an executable when it is executed.

So, the possible diagnosis to my mind is your framework is not able to be loaded by dyld properly some reason.
So, Under this hypothesis, in order to fix this you can go to the target's General tab and add the missing framework in the Embedded Binaries section.

Secondary, why don't you clean the Xcode project and derived data?

exit xcode

do command : rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

I wish it could be a little help.